# MacBook Air Won't Boot

Tags: macos, software-update

*** I did an update on my Macbook Retina 13" to the most recent version of Sierra OS X. The computer never gets past the Apple logo (black screen with a full progress bar). ***  This is a copy of the problem previously written up in November.  None of the solutions worked nor a few others.

Comment: Unless you provide more information on which specific steps you've tried and how they failed this looks like a duplicate of the question I assume you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I have maybe the solution, but it requires a USB key and an other computer on macOS. The solution consists to create a bootable USB key.
You can find here a good tutorial: [Bootable USB key macOS Sierra - MacWorld](http://www.macworld.com/article/3092900/macs/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-sierra-installer-drive.amp.html)
I had this problem too when I installed macOS Sierra (but after I downgraded because my CPU was overheating). I hope it will work for you